# /system/bin/sh: tcpdump: No such file or directory

Tags: android, linux, adb, tcpdump

I have generated a **tcpdump** file to run on an Android device using [this guide](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/monitoring-android-network-traffic-part-iii-installing-executing-tcpdump). Instead of `Fedora`, I made this file on `Ubuntu 12.04` .

Everything worked smoothly and **tcpdump** file was produced correctly. I copied `tcpdump` file at `/system/bin/` on Nexus-5 and ran following commands.

```
> adb shell
# ln -s /system/bin/tcpdump /system/xbin/tcpdump
# chmod 06755 /system/xbin/tcpdump
# reboot
```

After restarting computer, when I run `> adb shell tcpdump -h` , I get following error:

```
/system/bin/sh: tcpdump: No such file or directory
```

Can someone help me figure out the problem? Thanks!

Edit1:

When I run  "tcpdump -h" on my **Ubuntu** machine on **Virtualbox**, it shows me following result:

```
$ tcpdump -h
tcpdump version 4.2.1
libpcap version 1.1.1
Usage: tcpdump [-aAbdDefhHIKlLnNOpqRStuUvxX] [ -B size ] [ -c count ]
        [ -C file_size ] [ -E algo:secret ] [ -F file ] [ -G seconds ]
        [ -i interface ] [ -M secret ]
        [ -r file ] [ -s snaplen ] [ -T type ] [ -w file ]
        [ -W filecount ] [ -y datalinktype ] [ -z command ]
        [ -Z user ] [ expression ]
```

Then I copy this tcpdump file on Windows-7 host machine and copy it to the device.

Comment: /system/xbin/tcpdump or /system/bin/tcpdump ?

Comment: it shows only /bin, not /xbin. I copied tcpdump file in /xbin directory and ran that command. It still showed me the same problem.

Comment: Check the existence and permission bits of the binary after reboot.  Make sure it is built for that system, for example, put it in a temp directory under /data and try it there first, before adding the complication of putting it on a normally read-only partition which may be read-only not just at the file system level, but the underlying driver level as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that my tcpdump file was not statically compiled during the process.

After static compilation to include all other files, I still use `/system/xbin/tcpdump` to make it work.

You can also see comment section of the link above. I explained what went wrong exactly and how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I do now know what went wrong, but the following thing works:

https://github.com/chatch/tcpdump-android

It is a script that downloads, unpacks, configures and builds `tcpdump`. And yes, you can change the sources and rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we need to build application statically not with dynamic link. If we run in dynamic link it will shows no such file directory. So u have to run linux test application statically with your cross compiler tool chain and run in your platform like imx6 board